# Как сделать задержку с помощью прерываний?

Tags: c, dos, прерывания

В чем суть. Есть небольшая программа, которая работает в эмуляторе под dos с помощью библиотеки dos.h. Задача у программы простая: сохранить что-нибудь в буфер клавиатуры и с небольшой временной задержкой вывести на экран содержимое буфера. Но есть момент: всё нужно делать с помощью прерываний (низкоуровневыми функциями). Как сохранить в буфео клавиатуры с помощью прерываний я разобрался. А вот как задать задержку с помощью прерывания с использованием таймера реального времени я не понимаю. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>


int main(void)
{
  union REGS  rg;

  printf("Input from keyboard\n"
    "Press <ESC> to exit\n");

  while (1)
  {
    rg.h.ah = 0;
    int86(0x16, &rg, &rg);

    delay(500);

    printf("\nScan = %02.2X Ascii = %02.2X Normal = %c", rg.h.ah, rg.h.al, rg.h.al);
    if(rg.h.ah == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

То есть тут я задержку делаю с помощью delay(500), но нужно реализовать с помощью низкоуровненой функции.

Как можно вызывать прерывание с помощью таймера реального времени?

Comment: Если не усложнять, вешаете обработчик на int 8. он происходит 18.2 раза в секунду (55 ms). увеличивайте или уменьшайте в нем свою переменную. а в основной программе видимо крутитесь в цикле, пока эта переменная не достигнет нужного значения

Comment: А int 8 это системный таймер?

Comment: да, системный таймер